# Issue passing string using segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, uistoryboardsegue

I have one table view controller and another view controller. I want to pass data from selected cell (from table view) to view controller and update a label in view controller. I'm doing this by following way:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SubRecipeConnectorSegue"])
{
     RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     destViewController.recipeName = selectedRecipe;

 }
}
```

The problem is, when, for the 1st time I'm selecting a cell it not appearing in the label; but, when I'm selecting any 2nd value; my 1st selected value is displaying in label.
Similarly when selecting 3rd value, 2nd value is getting showed in label.
Can any one please tell me what is going wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to trigger the segue manually.  In IB, draw the segue from one VC to the other (not from the table cell).  Make sure to give it an identifier. In tableView:didSelect, set the selected string and call performSegueWithIdentifier:.

The problem you're seeing is the segue prep gets called before the tableView delegate, so the new VC is presenting the prior selection, which is undefined the first time.

Comment: I'm new to this.Could you please add or give sample code. what should I add "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#> sender:<#(id)#>] in (NSString*) and (id).If you could please give screenshot how to connect using segue, it would be great.Note:-I'm using story board.

Comment: Got a great post here:

www.distractionsoftware.com/2012/09/17/more-control-over-segues/ 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the data from the corresponding cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then perform the segue grammatically.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *recipeString = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubRecipeConnectorSegue" sender:recipeString];
}
```

Then change your prepareForSegue method into

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSString*)recipeString
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SubRecipeConnectorSegue"])
    {
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = recipeString;

    }
}
```

I don't know how you have stored the data in the cells, so that might differ from the example I wrote. If you need help implementing please let me know.